# Is it possible to complete the game 100% without using mods?

Tags: just-cause-2

I saw that [this mod](http://justcause2mods.com/component/content/article/1-front-page-news/65-100-completion-now-possible-with-new-mod.html) for *Just Cause 2* claims to 'add in missing elements' from a certain area to finally allow players to complete the game 'the proper way', by collecting all resource items and destroying all government property.

Does this mean that it's impossible to complete the game without modding it?  Has this been patched or something?

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. It appears to be a legitimate question.

Comment: I don't think "some guy, I forget who, said we're all playing the game wrong" is a good basis for a constructive and non-speculative question.  I've voted to close since I don't see an evidence to the contrary, or even a definition of "100%".

Comment: @MatthewRead I understand the idea behind that thought, but... Surely someone here has some expertise in the game, and can prove or disprove the inability to get 100% completion. This question strikes me more as *the entire reason this site exists*.

Comment: @MatthewRead - As to a definition of 100%, the save game screen indicates how much of the game you've completed on any particular save.

Comment: @SteveV Thanks. I'm wondering if we should edit the link to the mod into the question to help it sound less iffy?

Comment: I added the link to the mod in the question as suggested, if the original author disagrees with the edit, please feel free to revert.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*This answer is for the PC version of the game. I don't know if it's also true for the console versions.*

There is supposed to be one water tower in the game located at (18111,15326) which does not actually exist and 6 collectible items (3 weapon parts, 3 vehicle parts) which should be awarded at the completion of "Into The Den", but are not.  This means that players are stuck at 99.95% completion.

The mod you're thinking of can be found [[here]](http://justcause2mods.com/component/content/article/1-front-page-news/65-100-completion-now-possible-with-new-mod.html).

As of today (7/4/12), there are no official patches that I'm aware of to fix this.

Comment: There are achievements on the Xbox 360 and PS3 for completing the game 100%.  ...It seems strange to me that there would be impossible achievements in the console games... are you *sure* there's not been a patch to the disc-based versions of the game?

Comment: Just re-read your answer, you say the items were to be rewarded for completing the final agency mission?  Hm, didn't notice last time I played it on a console.  Will check again.

Comment: @GnomeSlicE - http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/just-cause-2/achievements/ and http://wikicheats.gametrailers.com/Just_Cause_2_-_PC_PS3_XB360/Achievements both seem to award the 'Perfectionist' achievement for 75% completion, not 100%